# error Failed to build the app: No package name found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, npm

[image]

When executing the command, the corresponding error occurs.
I'm curious as to what caused the error.
help me please...

tool: windows10,vscode,android studio

(I used a translator)

I reinstalled windows and configured the environment, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the package name is missing from your AndroidMenifest file.
Please add the package name as below

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.package">

</manifest>
```

Comment: That issue has been resolved. thank you!!